# Can't upload file to django via axios on remix / node.js

Tags: node.js, django-rest-framework, axios, remix.run

We have a remix application that takes a file upload and needs to forward it to a django backend (django rest framework). However, the django backend does not receive any data in the request.

On the remix backend we have an action that takes the file upload:

```js
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const user = await auth.isAuthenticated(request, {
    failureRedirect: paths.login,
  });

  const uploadHandler = unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler({
    maxPartSize: 500_000,
  });

  const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
    request,
    uploadHandler,
  );

  const response = await axios.post("/assets/upload/", formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });
};
```

Debugging into this action the formData looks fine. It has one entry ["myFile", ]. It seems like the Content-Length header does not get automatically generated. Django receives a value of 0 for Content-Length. However, a boundary is automatically added to the Content-Type header.

We tried a lot of things to fix this.
For example, reading the file from the FormData object into a Blob and creating a new FormData object with it:

```js
  const fileToBlob = async (file: File) =>
    new Blob([new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer())], { type: file.type });

  const formDataNew = new FormData();
  formDataNew.append(
    "myFile",
    await fileToBlob(formData.get("myFile") as File),
  );
```

Or using the form-data library to create a new FormData object and calculate and set the content-length header manually with `formDataFromLib.getHeaders()` or `"Content-Length": formDataFromLib.getLengthSync()`.
Or setting no headers at all (to let axios handle things - axios then sets content-type as `application/json`)... nothing worked.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Remix uses the `fetch` API, you can stream the body directly to your backend without the intermediate processing.

```js
// routes/upload.tsx
import {
  type ActionFunctionArgs,
  json,
} from "@remix-run/node";

import { Form, useActionData } from "@remix-run/react";

export const action = async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  // stream the request body directly to the backend endpoint
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/upload2", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      // get the content type from the original request
      // since it also includes the boundary needed by multipart/form-data
      "Content-Type": request.headers.get("Content-Type")!,
    },
    // just pass the request body through
    body: request.body,
  });

  const result = await response.json();
  return json(result);
};

export default function Component() {
  const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>();

  return (
    <div>
      <Form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(actionData, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And to verify, here's the "backend" endpoint. It will save to the `./uploads` directory.

```js
// routes/upload2.tsx
import {
  type ActionFunctionArgs,
  json,
  unstable_createFileUploadHandler,
  unstable_parseMultipartFormData,
} from "@remix-run/node";

export const action = async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const uploadHandler = unstable_createFileUploadHandler({
    directory: "./uploads",
    maxPartSize: 500_000,
  });

  const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
    request,
    uploadHandler
  );
  const file = formData.get("file") as File;

  return json({ success: true, filename: file.name });
};
```